# Calling a utility by name, without the full path, from cron doesn't work

Tags: linux, cron, environment-variables

I have some console utility installed. It's in `/usr/local/bin/my_utility`. I can call it as `my_utility` and it works well. I've created a cron task which runs a bash script. That bash script calls `my_utility`. The error which occurs only when I can the bash script via cron is "my_utility: command not found".

Why isn't it found? Running the bash script directly works well. Also, the script uses other env. variables with no failure.

Answer (score 1):

The system looks through the directories in `PATH` to find executables if you don't specify the full path. As such this is almost certainly because the `PATH` variable used by cron does not include `/usr/local/bin/`.

It's also possible that the utility is a script, and is not specifying the full path to its interpreter on the first (`#!`) line. If the path to this interpreter is in your `PATH` when logged in, but not in cron's `PATH` then you'd get a similar issue.

Generally speaking it's considered good practice to always use the full path in scripts to be run from cron, as cron may well have a different setting for `PATH` to you. The alternative is to call your script from cron as `/full/location/of/script`, and set a new value for `PATH` in the script.

We get this issue pop up a lot on FreeBSD because cron does not search under `/usr/local` by default, whereas most (if not all?) Linux distributions do.

Comment: `As such this is almost certainly because the PATH variable used by cron does not include /usr/local/bin/` -- why not? Why am I able to it as `my_utility` without specifing a full path?

Comment: I covered this in the answer. The system searches the directories listed in the `PATH` environmental variable when you try to run a command. It's perfectly possible for the shell used by cron to have a different setting for `PATH` to you.